# How to use multithreading in webscraping because without multithreading it takes a lot of time? Help me

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

```
from Application import app
from flask import redirect
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request, flash, jsonify
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello"

@app.route('/<string>')
def amazon(string):
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}
    url = "https://www.amazon.in/s?k="+string
    page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type':'s-search-result'})
    amazon_product=[]
    # item = results[0]
    for item in results:
        product={}
        atag = item.h2.a
        description = atag.text.strip()
        rurl = 'https://www.amazon.in'+atag.get('href')
        try:
            price_parent = item.find('span','a-price')
            price = price_parent.find('span','a-offscreen').text
        except AttributeError:
            continue
        
        try:
            rating = item.i.text
            review_count = item.find('span',{'class':'a-size-base','dir':'auto'}).text
        except AttributeError:
            rating = ""
            review_count = ""
        #print(len(results))
        product["description"]=description
        product["rurl"]=rurl
        product["price"]=price
        product["rating"]=rating
        product["review_count"]=review_count
        amazon_product.append(product)
    #print(jsonify(data)) 
    url = "https://www.flipkart.com/search?q="+string
    page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    results = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"_1AtVbE col-12-12"})
    product_name_Links = []
    flipkart_product=[]
    for i in results[3:-4]:
        if i.find_all('a') !=None:
            product_name_Links.append("https://www.flipkart.com"+i.find('a').get('href'))
    for i in product_name_Links:
        product={}
        prod_page = requests.get(i)
        prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(prod_page.text, "html.parser")
        try:
            prod_des = prod_soup.find('span',{'class':"B_NuCI"}).text
        except AttributeError:
            prod_des=""
        try:   
            prod_price = prod_soup.find('div',{'class':"_30jeq3 _16Jk6d"}).text[1:]
        except AttributeError:
            prod_price = ""
        try:
            prod_rating = prod_soup.find('div',{'class':"_3LWZlK _3uSWvT"}).text
        except AttributeError:
            prod_rating = ""
        try:
            prod_review = prod_soup.find('span',{'class':"_2_R_DZ"}).text 
        except AttributeError:
            prod_review = ""
        product["description"]=prod_des
        product["rurl"]=i
        product["price"]=prod_price
        product["rating"]=prod_rating
        product["review_count"]=prod_review
        flipkart_product.append(product)
    payload = {
        'amazon': amazon_product,
        'flipkart':flipkart_product
    }
    return jsonify(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multithreading, I recommend an asynchronous approach. This should speed up your application considerably.

There are many Python frameworks that are based on asynchronicity and are comparable to Flask. [This article](https://deepsource.io/blog/new-python-web-frameworks/) lists some of them.

The following example shows an implementation in [Quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart) that is almost identical to Flask. Instead of the requests library, [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/index.html) is used.
The code could certainly be improved, but the speed gain can already be seen here as well.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from functools import partial
from quart import Quart
from quart import request, jsonify

HEADERS = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36"}

app = Quart(__name__)

async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=HEADERS) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def parse(url, cb):
    html = await fetch(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    data = await cb(soup)
    return data

async def parse_amazon(soup):
    results = []
    elements = soup.find_all('div', {'data-component-type':'s-search-result'})
    for item in elements:
        atag = item.h2.a
        desc = atag.text.strip()
        rurl = f"https://www.amazon.in{atag.get('href')}"

        try:
            price_parent = item.find('span','a-price')
            price = price_parent.find('span','a-offscreen').text
        except AttributeError: continue

        try:
            rating = item.i.text
            review_count = item.find('span',{'class':'a-size-base','dir':'auto'}).text
        except AttributeError:
            rating = ''
            review_count = ''

        results.append({
            'description': desc,
            'rurl': rurl,
            'price': price,
            'rating': rating,
            'review_count': review_count,
        })
    return results

async def parse_flipkart(soup):
    elements = soup.find_all('div',{"class":"_1AtVbE col-12-12"})
    refs = [
        f"https://www.flipkart.com{e.find('a').get('href')}"
        for e in elements[3:-4] if e.find_all('a')
    ]

    return await asyncio.gather(*[
        parse(ref, partial(parse_flipkart_details, url=ref)) for ref in refs
    ])

async def parse_flipkart_details(soup, url):
    try:
        desc = soup.find('span',{'class':"B_NuCI"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        desc=""
    try:
        price = soup.find('div',{'class':"_30jeq3 _16Jk6d"}).text[1:]
    except AttributeError:
        price = ""
    try:
        rating = soup.find('div',{'class':"_3LWZlK _3uSWvT"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        rating = ""
    try:
        review = soup.find('span',{'class':"_2_R_DZ"}).text
    except AttributeError:
        review = ""
    return {
        'description': desc,
        'rurl': url,
        'price': price,
        'rating': rating,
        'review': review
    }

@app.route('/search')
async def search():
    qs = request.args.get('q')

    if not qs:
        return jsonify(amazon=[], flipkart=[])

    ret0,ret1 = await asyncio.gather(
        parse(f'https://www.amazon.in/s?k={qs}', parse_amazon),
        parse(f'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q={qs}', parse_flipkart),
    )
    return jsonify(amazon=ret0, flipkart=ret1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```